# Missing exchange tabs in AD

Tags: exchange-2007

I'm having a small problem and would be great if someone could help me out. I have exchange 2007 and Active Directory installed on my windows 7 machine. I'm not able to view exchange tabs in the Active Directory console. Is there any specifc installable / setting to get them enabled / displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Everything is done in the Exchange Management Console, MS did away with the Exchange tabs in ADUC on 2007.

Answer (score 0):

but i guess there is some installable which i had got installed in my Vista machine, and the exchange tabs were visible in AD.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use solutions like powergui and other powershell with form scripts to ease some processes... but as far as restoring that capability you have to go 3rd party.

try this link:
www.u-btech.com/products/exchange-tasks-2007.html

Cheers
xx